# Get crawl_args from ScrapyRt, and print them in terminal

Tags: api, rest, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I have this spider:

```
import scrapy
import re
import pandas as pd
from scrapy_engine.items import PjudItem


class updateSeekerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "updateSeeker"
    baseUrl = 'https://civil.pjud.cl/CIVILPORWEB/ConsultaDetalleAtPublicoAccion.do?TIP_Consulta=1&TIP_Cuaderno=1&CRR_IdCuaderno=31423178&ROL_Causa=123&TIP_Causa=C&ERA_Causa=2020&CRR_IdCausa=24963137&COD_Tribunal=58&TIP_Informe=1&'
    start_urls = [baseUrl]
    
    def parse(self, response):    
        print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>< here I want to print crawl_args')

        causa = PjudItem()
        resp = response.xpath("//script[contains(.,'vectoInformeHistoria[ind]')]")
        vector_list = resp.getall()

        pat = r"(?<=\().+?(?=\))"
        data = []
        for script in vector_list:
            data.append(re.findall(pat, script)[0].split(","))

        df_causas = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Etapa','Tramite','Descripcion','Fecha_tramite','foja'])
        causa['lastJudicialActionDate'] = df_causas.loc[0]['Fecha_tramite']
        causa['lastJudicialActionType'] = df_causas.loc[0]['Tramite']
        causa['lastJudicialActionDescription'] = df_causas.loc[0]['Descripcion']

        yield causa
```

And I have this curl request:

```
curl "http://127.0.0.1:9080/crawl.json?spider_name=updateSeeker&crawl_args=%7B%22zipcode%22%3A%2214100%22%7D&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcivil.pjud.cl%2FCIVILPORWEB%2FConsultaDetalleAtPublicoAccion.do%3FTIP_Consulta%3D1%26TIP_Cuaderno%3D1%26CRR_IdCuaderno%3D31423178%26ROL_Causa%3D123%26TIP_Causa%3DC%26ERA_Causa%3D2020%26CRR_IdCausa%3D24963137%26COD_Tribunal%3D58%26TIP_Informe%3D1%26"
```

the scrapyRt documentation miss to point out how I can accede this arguments in the scrapy part. Anyone knows how I could get the crawl_args, I need for build a list of urls on start_urls.

Answer (score 0):

`crawl_args` can be accessed in `parse` method or in other `scrapy.Spider` methods like

```
def parse(self, response):
    zipcode = sefl.zipcode
    url = self.url
```